# What's the difference between these two sets of nylon strings (Folk vs non-folk)?

Tags: strings, classical-guitar, tone

I was looking for nylon strings and noticed that Ernie Ball has two different sets available that are both gauge 28 to 42 and have ball ends.

One is sold as ["Ernesto Palla" Nylon](https://www.ernieball.com/guitar-strings/classical-guitar-strings/ernesto-palla-nylon-classical-guitar-strings#P02403), the other as ["Earthwood Folk Nylon"](https://www.ernieball.com/guitar-strings/classical-guitar-strings/earthwood-80-20-bronze-nylon-classical-guitar-strings).

[image][image]

What is the difference? Does "Folk" imply a particular tone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top package has silver and/or nickel windings on the bottom three strings, the bottom package has 80/20 bronze windings on the bottom three strings. That’s why the packages have those words on the front.

I’m not sure but I expect the top package has a brighter tone and is intended for classical style guitar. The bottom package probably has a darker sound that might be used more with folk, rock, and pop style playing.

Answer (score 2):

The term "folk guitar" is often used to describe a guitar which is designed for use with nylon strings like a classical guitar, but has a string spacing closer to that of an acoustic guitar and for whatever reason uses a tailpiece with notches for ball-end strings rather than one which is suitable for tying plain-end strings.  This latter "feature" has unfortunately resulted in many such instruments being strung with ball-end steel strings and consequently destroyed by the higher string tension.

Using plain-end nylon strings on a folk guitar would require affixing some sort of blobby thing at the end; I would guess that sliding on a bead and then using the flame from a match to melt the nylon string into a blob would probably work, but I've never tried that.  Using ball-end folk guitar strings is probably a much easier approach.  Tying the knot required for a classical guitar might be awkward with a ball-end string, but cutting off the ball end should yield a plain-end string suitable for use with a classical guitar that would otherwise have trouble with a ball-end string.

Comment: I have an ukulele with those bridge slots. There are ball end strings for those, but overhand knot works just fine.